# How to get url launcher to send an email?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I would like for someone to be able to click on a button "Contact me" and for this button to open up the email client with my email in there. I am currently just using the dummy data they give me on the package url_launcher 5.4.11.

This work properly when my url is 'https://flutter.dev'; but doesn't work when I try to enter a custom Supported URL scheme for sending an email.

The error I am getting is "Unhandled Exception: Could not launch smith@example.org?subject=Terra%20Tarot%20Question%20or%20Feedback
#0      _launchURL (package:tarotcards/screens/support.dart:11:5)
"

I read somewhere that it's not possible to call mail app on the iOS emulator. Is this true?

The issue is with my url in the _launchURL() method.
If you can help me fix this, that would be much appreciated. Thanks so much!

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'mailto:smith@example.org?subject=News&body=New%20plugin';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

class Support extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset('images/skull.png'),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20.0, 0, 10.0),
              child: Text(
                'Need some help?',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'Opensans',
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 0.0),
              child: Text(
                'Experiencing bugs? Want to request a feature?'
                'Feel free to get in touch with me.'
                ' ~Adriana',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    height: 1.5,
                    fontFamily: 'Opensans',
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40.0,
            ),
            ButtonTheme(
              //TODO:// make button #1 work!
              minWidth: 300.0,
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('CONTACT ME'),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Color(0XFFeb1555),
                onPressed: _launchURL,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40.0,
            ),
            ButtonTheme(
              //TODO:// make button #2 work!
              minWidth: 300.0,
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS'),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                textColor: Colors.black,
                color: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  print('second button tapped');
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 150.0,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text(
                'Terms of Service & Privacy Policy →',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0XFFeb1555),
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                print('privacy policy tapped');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't reproduce the error on my machine for real device!

Are you using the simulator? Remember that the simulator cannot handle mailto because the mail application is not available.

Try:

```
_launchURL() async {
  final url =
      Uri.encodeFull('mailto:smith@example.org?subject=News&body=New plugin');
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

You can try this package instead of on a real device:
[flutter_email_sender](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender#-readme-tab-)

Comment: Hello . Yes I am using a simulator. Good to know about the simulator not workign with mailto. i will try your solution. thank you :)

Comment: Quick question: What do I do if I have two different buttons with two different urls?

Comment: How exactly? Like you want each button to send to a different email?

Comment: Yes. Correct. I would like one button to open an email and the other one to open a website. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I figured it out! I just created a new method call for the other button.   _launchSupportWebsite() async {
  const String url = 'http://flutter.dev';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

Comment: You could've used the same method as such:
```
_launchURL(String url) async {
  final link =
      Uri.encodeFull(url);
  if (await canLaunch(link)) {
    await launch(link);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $link';
  }
}
```
Then in the buttons:

onPressed: () => _launchURL('mailto:smith@example.org?subject=News&body=New plugin'),

or

onPressed: () => _launchURL('flutter.dev'),

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add that for `API >= 30` the following is needed to be added to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for email sending to work.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

[source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63727)